# copied codeigniter app from web server to xampp, links dont work

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

i tranfered a copy of a codeigniter app i made to transfer the code to Codeigniter Bootstrap https://github.com/sjlu/CodeIgniter-Bootstrap;

i changed the baseurl to 'localhost/{dir name}', changed the links, default controller. the first page loads fine, but all the links redirect back to the localhost, i am sure its something stupid i am missing, but i cant figure out what it is? the source, if i type localhost/{controller}/{function} with an echo to test it, it wont load the function

Comment: what error you are getting.............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to write `.htaccess`..

```
#php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
#php_value post_max_size 200M
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|indexcp\.php?|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_/.-]+)$ index.php?/welcome/$1 

RewriteRule ^(CSI) index.php?/CSI
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

I have added in you repo